# How to compare the input of the user to the file text?

Tags: python

How can I compare the input of the user to the file text? In my text file, I have this word, "HELLO WORLD". I tried to input the HELLO WORLD, but it does not found and meet the 2nd condition. Any ideas?

```
import os 
f = open('text file')
text = f.read().strip().split()
answer = input(": ").upper().split()
if answer in text:
    print("FOUND NOW")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND") #This is the one printing
```

Comment: you are trying to compare two lists with `in`, which doesn't work

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Why do you use `split()`? Just let the text be text and compare `if answer == text:`

Comment: @depperm _technically_ it works. E.g. `[1] in [[1], [2]]` => `True`. The problem is that the list `["HELLO WORLD"]` is not a member of the list `["HELLO WORLD"]`

Comment: @ThomasWeller If I remove that, I have this error: 
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: @ThomasWeller in additional, it still meet the 2nd condition, NOT FOUND. Tried now.

Comment: Why are you using `split` at all? `text = "HELLO WORLD"; answer = "HELLO WORLD"; if answer == text: ...`.

Comment: If you get an error message as mentioned by you, there cannot be additional output as mentioned by you. You need to remove both `split()`

Comment: @chepner I am using a file handling

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if using `in` that wouldn't matter at all, otherwise just use `.strip`, so at the end that shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you do `text = f.read().strip().split()`, it splits by *all whitespace*, so you get `text = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']`

`in` checks for membership. `a in b` can be written in long form as a function like so:

```
def check_in(a, b):
    for item in b:
        if a == item:
            return True
    return False
```

So when you have two lists, both containing a single string:

```
a = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
b = ["HELLO", "WORLD", "foo", "bar"]
```

Let's see how the `in` function would work.

```
# Iteration 0:
item = "HELLO"
a = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
is a == item? FALSE

# Iteration 1:
item = "WORLD"
a = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
is a == item? FALSE


# Iteration 2:
item = "foo"
a = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
a == item? FALSE

# Iteration 3:
item = "bar"
a = ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
a == item? FALSE
```

Since none of the items were `== a`, we get `False`.

You seem to want to check if the string input from the user is the same as one of the lines in your file, so either specify that you want to `split()` the input file on `'\n'`, or read the file line-by-line and strip each line. Also, you shouldn't `split()` the user's input.

```
# Use with to read files, automatically closes the file after the with block is done
with open('text file') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().upper() for line in f]

answer = input(": ").upper()

if answer in lines:
    print("FOUND NOW")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: It is printing Not found

Comment: `lines = [line.strip().upper() for line in f]`, you definitely don't need to store two lists in memory

Comment: @DagonTooth Not for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGPw.png

Comment: @Matiiss thanks! I started off with `lines = f.readlines()` and forgot to remove `.readlines()` when I added the comprehension

Comment: This is much clearer!

Comment: also IMO it would be better to not save the file to a list at all, just record the user answer before opening file, then open file and iterate over lines (without saving them anywhere) and check each line if it matches answer, then if it matches, print out found and break out, and use an `else` on the `for` loop to print not found

Comment: @Matiiss we don't know if OP uses the list for something later, so I let it remain a list. If it's only used once, I agree with you

Comment: @PranavHosangadi right, that is actually what I did consider at some point but I guess I forgot, but then you can easily use `lines = f.readlines()` I think it removes the newlines so no need for stripping

Comment: @Matiiss `readlines()` leaves newline characters in.

Answer (score 0):

`str.split` returns a list. You could use `readline` and just compare to the input:

```
with open('text file') as f:
    text = map(str.strip, f.readlines())
answer = input(": ").upper()
if answer in text:
    print("FOUND NOW")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND") #This is the one printing
```

Comment: The 2nd condition is printed. I want to meet the first condition, which I want it to be found.

Comment: I edited my answer, you should have a careful look at your file contents, but one solution would be to use `in` instead of `==`

Comment: also better to iterate over the file line by line

Comment: OP stated that the file contents were `HELLO WORLD`

Comment: Edited my answer to include multiple lines

Comment: @Jab ok, I guess for that one line it wouldn't really matter if `.readline` or iteration was used (except iteration would require an additional line of code), but in case of multiple lines it would be better to iterate over the file object

Comment: @Matiiss how can I iterate over the file object?

Comment: @DagonTooth `for line in f: if line == answer: ...` (or `in`) (this has to be done inside the context manager (`with`)), but then you have to move `answer = input(': ')` before the context manager (or at least before iterating)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, removing both `.split()` calls will solve the issue:

```
import os 
f = open('text file')
text = f.read().strip() #.split() <- remove here
answer = input(": ").upper() #.split() <- remove here
if answer in text:
    print("FOUND NOW")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Depending on your needs, you probably do not want an `in` comparison, but an equality comparison using `==`:

```
import os 
f = open('text file')
text = f.read().strip() #.split()
answer = input(": ").upper() #.split()
if answer == text: # replaced in
    print("FOUND NOW")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

The difference is: `HELLO` is also **in** (part of) `HELLO WORLD`, but `HELLO` is not equal to `HELLO WORLD`.